# DataTable - count values available in another datatable

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatables

I'm using DataTable and Editor. How can I count values available in another datatable? I would like to count (or have the number) how often a value is available in table_02 and display it in column count of table_01.

table_01:

```
id | value | count
1|value_01|{count of value_01 in table_02}
2|value_02|{count of value_02 in table_02}
3|value_03|{count of value_03 in table_02}
4|value_04|{count of value_04 in table_02}
5|value_05|{count of value_05 in table_02}
```

table_02:

```
foreign_id | value
1|value_01
1|value_01
1|value_01
3|value_03
5|value_05
5|value_05
```

I can count the records in table_02 and display it in table_01 (see below). But how can I filter or only count e.g. values with 'foreign_id' '1' ?

```
table_01 = $('#table_01').DataTable( {
    dom: "Blfrtip",
    ajax: {
          url: "source_01.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: function (d) { 
                    d.selectUserID = userID;                         
                    } },
    serverSide: true,
    processing: true,
    columns: [
        { data: "name" },
        { data: "id" },
        { data: "user_id", visible: false },
        { data: "count" ,
            "render": function () {
                var json = table_02.ajax.json().data;                   
                return json.length; 
            }               
        }                              
    ],
    ...
```

consol.log(json.length):  11

consol.log(json) is:

```
[Object { DT_RowId="row_1",  table_01={...},  table_02={...},  more...}, 
Object { DT_RowId="row_47",  table_01={...},  table_02={...},  more...},
... 
Object { DT_RowId="row_41",  table_01={...},  table_02={...},  more...}, 
Object { DT_RowId="row_46",  table_01={...},  table_02={...}, more...}]
```

and further where ...

```
table_01 = Object { value="Test 01",  user_id="1"}
table_02 = Object { account_id="1",  user_id="1",  uid_foreign="1",  more...}
```

Is it possible to loop through json and only render the object where e.g. table_02.uid_foreign = 1 so I can do a .length on the filtered result?

Comment: If you have server-side processing mode on, you will only be able to count records from single page. You would need to use client-side processing mode instead to have access to all data or count records on the server.